# binding variables to compiled elements in angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am dynamically creating an element with angular.  When the app initally runs using app.run() the element is created and I compile the element, after compiling the element I add an ng-show="active" so I can toggle the visibility of the element and possibly animate a transition later using that directive.  The only problem is the compiled element only binds once it looks like to the variable active. Once its set to true it won't hide again. Do  I need to use digest or some other method to get it the binding to work properly?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        .message-app { width:100px; height:30px; background-color:#005cab; color:white; text-align:center; line-height:30px; margin-bottom:5px; }
        .app-console { width:300px; height:30px; border:1px solid red; }
    </style>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">

    <div class="message-app" val=''>click</div>
    <div class="message-app" val='true'>click</div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("messageApp", []);

    app.run(function($rootScope){

        $rootScope.message = angular.element("<div class='app-console' ng-show='active'></div>");


        angular.element(document.body).append($rootScope.message);

    })

    function AppCtrl($scope, $compile, $rootScope){

        $scope.active = false;


        $compile($rootScope.message)($scope);

        $scope.setActive = function(val){

            $scope.active = val;
            $scope.$apply();
        }

    }

    app.directive("messageApp", function(){

        return {

            restrict:"C",
            controller:"AppCtrl",
            scope:{

                val:"@"

            },
            link:function(scope, element, attr){

                element.bind("click", function(){

                    scope.setActive(Boolean(scope.val));

                })

            }

        }

    })

    angular.element(document).ready(function(){

        angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector("html"), ["messageApp"])

    })

</script>
```

To make this simple I didn't put the js in a separate file.  Is there something that I am doing wrong with this?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using the `.run()` function to setup the dom? Why not use a directive for your dynamic element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glossing over the downsides of doing DOM manipulation in `.run` the issue you're having is related to your directive's isolated scopes.

When you call `setActive()` from the directive all the scope references inside `setActive()` are to the calling object's scope (which is the directive's isolate scope).  So you're currently manipulating a property `active` on each directive's isolate scope.  What you want, however, is to change `active` on the `appCtrl` scope.

To accomplish this I'd get rid of `setActive()` and do this entirely in your directive with these 3 steps:

1) Add `active` to your directive's scope:

```
scope:{
  val:"@",
  isactive: "="
},
```

2) Pass `active` to your directive:

```
<div class="message-app" val='' isactive="active">click</div>
<div class="message-app" val='true' isactive="active">click</div>
```

3) Change `active` directly in your click handler:

```
element.bind("click", function(){
  scope.$apply(function() {
     scope.isactive =Boolean(scope.val);
  });
});
```

Now you don't need to worry about having your directive talk to your controller, or about which scope you're on.  And you've got a clear interface to your directive.

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zF3Xp/)

Comment: Looking at it yes, I should of generated the element on the AppCtrl, not the run function. I am still learning angular and the best practices. With that said would I be able to bind the active variable using a Data service using something like app.factory("Data", function(){ var data = { active:false } return data; })

Comment: Sure, you could inject that service into your controller.  And then your controller would just need to bind the returned value to the scope.

Comment: thank you for your help I understand the scope "=" and how it works now would you have an an example of how to do that, Bind a data service to a dynamically created element after its run through $compile?

Comment: Its really close to what I had in mind I wanted a way to do it without the isactive in there using the Data instead of is active but I guess you would have to contain the variable in the $scope, by doing something like $scope.data = Data; then passing that to the ng-show

Comment: I really appreciate your help I learned quite a bit from your fiddles.

Comment: If you'd like to simplify things, your current code could be simplified to just using `ngclick` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/vBh3d/).  Just in case that gives you more options.